# Ошибка подключении JSTL зависимости в Maven

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet, jstl, http-status-code-500

получаю ряд ошибок 500 уровня при запуске проекта через Tomcat 10.1.15. Использую Meven для сборки и подключаю следующие зависимости:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
     <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

и

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
     <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Вот web.xml [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее в файле jsp подключаю

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`
```

Выполняю фазу package и в целевой папке targer наблюдаю следующие зависимости: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее запускаю и получаю ряд ошибок: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнительная информация которая может помочь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь решать проблему 5 часов, пробовал много способов. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Answer (score 0):

Подключаемый таглиб относится к библиотеке jstl более ранней версии.

Неправильно:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Правильно:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Изменил, теперь ошибка изменила вид на:  Unable to find taglib [c] for URI: [jakarta.tags.core]

Comment: Это означает, что библиотека с тэгами отсутствует при деплое.

Comment: Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Если она указана в зависимостях, то должна попадать туда сама.

Comment: Так они указаны (если они верны конечно - те что выше).

Comment: Да, но почему-то сервер их не находит, смотри логи.

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.